# How do I make custom player heads have a NBT tag with commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to put a CanPlaceOn NBT tag on a custom player head and I don't know where to put the tag. I tried

```
/give @p minecraft:player_head{{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stone"]}  
display: {Name:"{\"text\":\"Bomb\"}"},  
SkullOwner:{Id:[I;-1953510240,1753235720,-1536533983,839781756],  
Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvOGRhMzMyYWJkZTMzM2ExNWE2YzZmY2ZlY2E4M2YwMTU5ZWE5NGI2OGU4ZjI3NGJhZmMwNDg5MmI2ZGJmYyJ9fX0="}]}}} 1
```

and

```
/give @p minecraft:player_head{  
display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Bomb\"}"},  
SkullOwner:{Id:[I;-1953510240,1753235720,-1536533983,839781756],  
Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvOGRhMzMyYWJkZTMzM2ExNWE2YzZmY2ZlY2E4M2YwMTU5ZWE5NGI2OGU4ZjI3NGJhZmMwNDg5MmI2ZGJmYyJ9fX0="}]}}}  
{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stone"]} 1
```

I don't know what to do to add the NBT tag in the correct place.

Answer (score -1):

I noticed that you are missing commas between the parts of your command. You always need commas and proper brackets.

But anyways it should look something like this:

```
/give @p player_head{SkullOwner:{Id:[I;-122210,6844,135344,-13688],Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvOGRhMzMyYWJkZTMzM2ExNWE2YzZmY2ZlY2E4M2YwMTU5ZWE5NGI2OGU4ZjI3NGJhZmMwNDg5MmI2ZGJmYyJ9fX0="}]}},display:{Name:'[{"text":"Bomb","italic":false}]'},CanPlaceOn:[stone]} 1
```

I just used an online player head generator but I'll link it here: https://www.gamergeeks.net/apps/minecraft/give-command-generator/player-heads

Comment: [People are under no obligation to explain why they downvoted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325416/566903)

Comment: But it works...